# Sequelize bulkCreate from JSON File

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to create JSON file with records to insert and then use model.bulkCreate to insert all records at once but when I read file I get "TypeError: records.map is not a function"

database.js

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/databaseTables/consoleAndPlatform.json", function(err, data){
    ConsoleAndPlatform.bulkCreate(data.toString())
  })
```

consoleAndPlatform.json

```
[{console: "XBOX",
platform: "XBOX 360",
name: "Xbox 360"},{
console: "XBOX",
platform: "XBOX ONE",
name: "Xbox One"},{
console: "XBOX",
platform: "XBOX LIVE",
name: "Xbox Live"},{
console: "PS",
platform: "PS4",
name: "Playstation 4"}]
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found solution maybe it will be helpful for someone. First of all JSON was wrong, should be:

```
[
{
    "console": "XBOX",
    "platform": "XBOX 360",
    "name": "Xbox 360"
},
{
    "console": "XBOX",
    "platform": "XBOX ONE",
    "name": "Xbox One"
},
{
    "console": "XBOX",
    "platform": "XBOX LIVE",
    "name": "Xbox Live"
}]
```

and second you need to JSON.parse the string result:

```
ConsoleAndPlatform.bulkCreate(JSON.parse(data.toString()))
```